# Phone freeze on making bitmap of Canvas View in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-bitmap

i am trying to make an Paint app with Canvas View, and i want when user painting anything on canvas , i copy that he paint on Image View that is under my canvas view and Encode bitmap and send it to other users with socket.
my problem is that when my code is making bitmap from canvas, phone being laggy for 2 second.
i use thread but my problem still here.
what shall i do? this is my code

```
 new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (i++ < 1000) {
                    try {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {

try {
    Bitmap bitmap = canvas.getBitmap();

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;
    bitmap = canvas.getScaleBitmap(width, height);
    bytes = canvas.getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100);



    socket.emit("message",encodeToBase64(Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getBitmap()),Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,10));
   img.drawBitmap( Bitmap.createBitmap(canvas.getBitmap()));
bitmap.recycle();

}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
                                }


                        });
                        Thread.sleep(5000);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG....Try JPEG

Comment: @Kabir still laggy

Comment: while (i++ < 1000) ....condition terminate or not?

Comment: @Kabir not . . . . .

Comment: I am not sure about what is your complete code.You are facing problem with large bitmap.Please refere this link for handling large bitmap in android.https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap